# Substr giving incorrect output in sql in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have table ot.plan:

which has

```
NAME                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXISTS(SELECT 1 from zzz_temp b where SUBSTR(a.hehrircal,1,4)=b.acc_num         
EXISTS(SELECT 1 from zzz_temp b where SUBSTR(a.clinet,1,4)=b.acc_num
```

my expected output is:

```
 NAME                                                                            
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    zzz_temp
    zzz_temp
```

I tried:

```
select SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'from')+5,INSTR(name,'b')) from ot.plan;
```

Its giving me output :

```
zzz_temp b where SUBSTR(a.hehri
zzz_temp b where SUBSTR(a.cline
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Consider using [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303) instead.

Comment: As has been answered, the second parameter for `INSTR` is the length, not the end position. Also be aware, that your b detection only works correctly as long as the table name doesn't contain a b. You could look for `' b '` (leading and trailing blank) instead.

Comment: select SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'from')+5,INSTR(name,' b')-INSTR(name,'from')+5) from ot.plan; still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result using the `regexp_substr` as follows:

```
Select regexp_substr(name, 'from (.+) b',1,1,null,1)
  From ot.plan;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be thinking that the last parameter is the position to stop at.  It is actually the number of characters to include in the result.

Try subtracting the starting position from the end position to determine the length.

Comment: select SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'from')+5,INSTR(name,' b')-INSTR(name,'from')+5) from ot.plan; still not working

Comment: @Randomguy in the last expression, you need to subtract the 5 (and possible shift it by 1 either up or down) . If your first expression is `N+5`, the second should be `B-(N+5)` or `B-N-5`.

Answer (score 1):

> select SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'from')+5,INSTR(name,' b')-INSTR(name,'from')+5) from ot.plan; still not working

You're trying to subtract one number from another, but as part of that you have an addition. You either need to enclose the second part in parentheses:

```
select SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'from')+5,INSTR(name,' b')-(INSTR(name,'from')+5)) from ot.plan;

SUBSTR(NAME,INSTR(NAME,'FROM')+5,INSTR(NAME,'B')-(INSTR(NAME,'FROM')+5)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
zzz_temp
zzz_temp
```

or change the plus to a minus:

```
select SUBSTR(name,INSTR(name,'from')+5,INSTR(name,' b')-INSTR(name,'from')-5) from ot.plan;

SUBSTR(NAME,INSTR(NAME,'FROM')+5,INSTR(NAME,'B')-INSTR(NAME,'FROM')-5) 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
zzz_temp
zzz_temp
```

You can look at the individual numbers involved to understand what it's doing:

```
select
  INSTR(name,'from') as start_from,
  INSTR(name,'from')+5 as start_table,
  INSTR(name,' b') as b,
  INSTR(name,' b')-(INSTR(name,'from')+5) as length_a,
  INSTR(name,' b')-INSTR(name,'from')-5 as length_b
from ot.plan;

START_FROM START_TABLE          B   LENGTH_A   LENGTH_B
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        17          22         30          8          8
        17          22         30          8          8
```

The first three are the positions of the characters you're searching for; the lengths are the two variations on the subtraction - so overall showing that you're looking for 8 characters starting from position 22.

However, given the fragility of this as mentioned in comments, you're probably better off with the regular expression approach anyway.